# An error was raised by libgit2. Category = 21 (MergeConflict)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am using VS 2013.

I am stuck.  Everything is committed to my local repository.  I try to pull from remote and I get the following error:

*An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = 21 (MergeConflict).
1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge*

I have no uncommitted changes...that I'm aware of.

Comment: When I got this error I resolved it by committing or undoing all my changes locally. Only then was I able to start resolving my conflicts through the GUI. @Dan - I know this wasn't the problem in your case, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like running git pull from the command prompt allowed me to execute the pull. I was unfamiliar with the command prompt.

Comment: which command prompt? I tried cmd, the package manager, command window... `git pull` did not work on any of them.. what folder should i be in when i run this?

Comment: @Juventus18 Do you have git installed?  Did you get an error message when you tried git pull?

Comment: Yes, it is installed, at least installed in VS. I was previously using the VS2013 GUI interface, but then I got a similar error to yours when  trying to pull changes into my repo. when I try to run `git pull` from VS "Command Window" I get error "Command git is not valid", which command prompt should I be using? what folder should I be in when I run the command?

Comment: @Juventus18 I think if you download git from [http://git-scm.com/download/win](http://git-scm.com/download/win) and install it that should take care of your issue.  Once installed, try running git pull again.  Sorry, it's been a while so I'm trying to remember exactly what I did.

Comment: OK, i figured it out. I didn't have to reinstall git, but on the "Changes" window in VS Team Explorer, you can drop down the "Actions" link and there is an option there "open command prompt". Running `git pull` here told me which file was causing problems and i was able to rectify the situation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you will see this message when you have modified a file, but not staged the changes, and the merge you are attempting would write to that file.  Visual Studio 2013, unfortunately, contains a bug where it determines that your file is modified even though it is not.  The bug manifests when you have a file in your repository that has line endings that disagree with what should have been produced, given your `core.autocrlf` settings.

This bug is fixed in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432

Comment: I installed the update and now I get the same error except for Category = 21 it now says Category = ssh.

Comment: That's actually a different error:  Visual Studio does not support ssh remotes.

Comment: But I have not done anything differently.  I installed the update and tried to sync.  I am not using ssh that I'm aware of.

Comment: Oh!  My mistake, I'm sorry, I did misread that.  Does `git status` show anything?  Can you post a screenshot of the Team Explorer Changes page?  (I just want to cover all the bases.)

Comment: Looks like running `git pull` from the command prompt allowed me to execute the pull.  I was unfamiliar with the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

undo your web config file from the "exclude changes" section at "team explorer". hope it will work.it works for me.